# Time speed in deep space

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, time, time-dilation, observers

Time goes farster when you leave earths gravitational feild. Is there a danger that if we were in deep space and moving slowly we would age considerably compared to people on earth?

Comment: Stewart, in your own reference frame, you don't live any longer by going faster or slower, or by getting far away from gravitational fields.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. The effect is too small to be noticeable without extremely precise equipment (this is also why it wasn't noticed until the 20th century).

The [equation for gravitational time dilation is](https://users.sussex.ac.uk/~waa22/relativity/What_is_gravitational_time_dilation.html):

$t_f = t_i \sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$

(note GM/r is the gravitational potential)

Put in appropriate values for $G$, $M_{Earth}$, $r_{Earth}$, and the speed of light $c$ and you'll find that the change is so small that the time difference is not even a second for a standard human lifetime. Therefore, you will not age considerably relative to someone on Earth if you're in deep space.

Answer (score 0):

No. The slowing down on earth is just a little bit compared to free space (without any spacetime curvature). So by going into deeper and deeper space does not make it worse.

You should be careful around black holes, though. There you have significant curvature and that can become a problem.

Comment: Martin perhaps you are right but one can't be sure about this. Differences in time of flight for signals from satellite in outer space from the expected value as well as the unexpected velocity of rotation of the outer parts of galaxies could be an evidence that the real distribution of gravitational potential is different from Einsteins equation. ;-)

Comment: Okay, I assumed that General Relativity holds and that we are not in a deep dark matter well or something like that. I actually did not think of this, I just thought that compared to the gravitational force on the earth, being somewhere away from objects will reduce the gravitational pull such that the time dilation should be negligible. My main point is that time should only be able to slow down, not accelerate to an infinite pace. Assuming that the slowing down on earth is finite, of course :-).

Comment: I wasn't thinking that time acceleration could be infinite Martin just relatively significant. I surprised this hasn't already been calculated. Do they even know how much faster people will age if they live on mars instead of earth, mars being a smaller planet and further from the suns gravitational field?